# Uncaught Error: Rendered fewer hooks than expected. This may be caused by an accidental early return statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

i have this function component as part of my project. i haven't called any hook inside loops, conditions, or nested functions as stated in the [react document](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level). i also have placed my hooks before any return statement so that react can reach each of them. yet i get this error which says *Uncaught Error: Rendered fewer hooks than expected. This may be caused by an accidental early return statement*.

any idea what the problem is ?

```
function ScrollRenderingCom(props) {
const { children, aproximateHeight = 200} = props;
const [isIntersecting, setIsIntersecting] = useState(false);
const fakeComponent = useRef(null);


const callback = useCallback((entries) => {
    const [entry] = entries;
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        setIsIntersecting(true)
    }
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    const options = {
        root: null,
        rootMargin: '0px',
        threshold: 0,
    }
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
    observer.observe(fakeComponent.current);
    return () => {
        observer.disconnect();
    }
}, [callback]);

return (
    isIntersecting ? children 
                    : 
                    <div 
                        ref={fakeComponent}
                        className={children.type().props.className}
                        style={{ visibility: 'hidden',
                                 minHeight: aproximateHeight + 'px' }}
                    >
                    </div>
  )
}
```

and this is the component stack trace that react prints to the console which specifies the error occurred in this component

> The above error occurred in the ScrollRenderingCom component:

```
at ScrollRenderingCom (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:3468:5)
at div
at PostSection1
at Home
at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:229775:5)
at div
at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:229708:15)
at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:228517:5)
at App
```

**Update:**

from negative reflections, i noticed that my sample code is insufficient to reproduce the issue. hence i provide the above component with a single Child component so that it can be run and inspected in isolation.
here is the Child component

```
function Child() {
const [successMessage, setSuccessMessage] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    if (successMessage) {
        alert('this app works correctly')
    }
    return () => {setSuccessMessage(false)}
})

const handleOnClick = () => {
    setSuccessMessage(true);
}
return(
    <div className="child"
         style={{width: '500px', 
                 height: '200px',
                 backgroundColor: 'green',
                 color: 'white'
                }} 
    >
        <h1>this component should be rendered when
            the empty blue div element completely 
            enters the viewport
        </h1>
        <h3>if you see the above message click Yes</h3>
        <button onClick={handleOnClick} >Yes</button>
    </div>
   )
}
```

**and here is the final [live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/demo-ji692r?file=/src/App.js) that you can inspect the problem.**

please let me know of any further deficiencies in my question and give me a chance to fix them before downing me

Comment: How are you sure that this error is specifically related to this Component?

Comment: @Kostas i edited my question and included the error that react prints to the console

Comment: I think we need a bit more context in the form of a [mcve]. Could you also try creating a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: I already gave you the answer. Your codesanbox is empty

Comment: @DrewReese live demo is available now

Comment: I still don't see your changes in codesandbox. You have created new files but they're empty

Comment: @KonradLinkowski
 i fixed it see if it works for you

Comment: My answer is still applicable and works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73430348/uncaught-error-rendered-fewer-hooks-than-expected-this-may-be-caused-by-an-acc/73433370#73433370

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By calling `children.type` you create that component and that's causing hooks to be run conditionally.

Try changing:

```
children.type().props.className
```

to

```
children.props.className
```

No need to create the component here

https://codesandbox.io/s/demo-forked-egofes?file=/src/ScrollRenderingCom.js:816-825

Comment: that works perfectly. the only ambiguity here is that when i log children.props to the console  there is no className in the props object. that's actually what made me think i need to call the children function first so it returns the actual dom elements which contain classes. is className somewhere deep in prototype chain of children.props object?

Comment: You have never passed any props to `<Child />`, that's why `children.props` is an empty object

Comment: then how className is a property of `children.props`

Comment: It's `undefined` for me

Comment: i just noticed that. so the source of error is now resolved but your solution is not the best because it doesn't copy `className` of children inside the returned empty div element as the original code does. i found that the best solution without damaging the original behavior of the code  would be to call the `children.type` on the top level of the component and save it into a variable so we can safely use it inside `className` of the returned div element

Comment: You can do it, but it's kind of spaghetti and I wouldn't do that.